# Where do server-side .rb scripts that don't handle user requests (e.g. scripts run by cron) go?

Tags: ruby, cron, server-side

I'm building a website (hosted on GoDaddy) that will display graphs and charts about data obtained via another website's API. The other website updates its data only once a day, so I only need to make an API call once a day to get up-to-date info. Here's my plan:

- A Ruby script on my hosting server's filesystem does the API call, and saves relevant info to .txt files on that local filesystem.
- Another Ruby script generates a whole bunch of PHP files based on a bunch of different slices and dices of the data in those .txt files. (The PHP files are what process user requests)
- Both of the above scripts are run as cron jobs, once per day.

To rephrase my question: Where do server-side scripts, which are agnostic toward user requests, get placed on the website's file system, specifically if a user is never supposed to see them or even really know they exist? (Or am I mistaken in assuming a setup like `/ruby/script.rb` is bad practice because people could directly access that file via a web browser?)

Or is my whole approach to this fundamentally flawed? I should clarify that I'm doing this project to teach myself Ruby and learn more about web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `/srv` if placed by the sysadmin, in `/usr/share/<appname>` if packaged up.

Answer (score 0):

When they're for your use only it's up to you. For commands that run on the command-line, I usually put them in ~/bin. Shared files used by them go in ~/lib, or you can create a subdirectory of bin for the lib files: ~/bin/lib.

Files/apps under development usually go in a ~/dev or ~/development directory.